# string.Format in XElement not formatting

Tags: c#, xml, string

I'm trying to format an XML element with three strings padded to 10 characters with spaces. Here is the code I'm using.

The three strings are set in the model.

```
    public string a{ get; set; }
    public string b{ get; set; }
    public string c{ get; set; }
```

and then formated to an XElement

```
var itemElement = new XElement("item",
                            new XElement("abc", string.Format("{0:-10}{1:-10}{2:-10}", i.a, i.b, i.c))
                    );
```

it should be producing "a(padding)b(padding)c(padding)", but is producing "abc" within the node.

Any ideas?

Comment: for `a(padding)b(padding)c(padding)` wouldn't you need  `string.Format("{0:10}{1:10}{2:10}", i.a, i.b, i.c)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct `String.Format` syntax is to use a comma for alignment, not a colon:

```
string.Format("{0,-10}{1,-10}{2,-10}", i.a, i.b, i.c)
```

[Per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx):

> The syntax of a format item is as
>   follows:
>
> {index[,length][:formatString]}

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping in an CData element:

```
var itemElement = new XElement("item", 
    new XCData(
        new XElement("abc", string.Format("{0:-10}{1:-10}{2:-10}", i.a, i.b, i.c))));
```

You need this, because whitespace is not considered significant by XML parsers by default. An alternative to using CData would be the [xml:space](http://www.simonstl.com/xmlprim/xmlupdate/atts.html) attribute, which should also produce the desired result. See [this MSDN page for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256097.aspx) details.